# .ffill() overwriting existing values

Tags: pandas

Here is a time series we can interpret as state transitions:

```
states = list('abc')
transition_times = [
  pd.to_datetime('00:01:00'),
  pd.to_datetime('00:03:10'),
  pd.to_datetime('00:05:00'),
]
df = pd.DataFrame({'state': states}, index=transition_times);df


Out:
                            state
     2018-01-11 00:01:00    a
     2018-01-11 00:03:10    b
     2018-01-11 00:05:00    c
```

Suppose I now want a minute indexed timeline of the system's state from 00:01:00 to 00:05:00. My idea was :

```
df.resample('1min').ffill()

Out:
                            state
     2018-01-11 00:01:00    a
     2018-01-11 00:02:00    a
     2018-01-11 00:03:00    a  <- I would expect 'b' here !
     2018-01-11 00:04:00    b
     2018-01-11 00:05:00    c
```

As annotated, could someone explain why the [3min,4min[ bin was filled forward with 'a' ?

I can reveal the gaps that I expected to be filled by doing:

```
df.resample('1min').max()

Out:
                    state
     2018-01-11 00:01:00    a
     2018-01-11 00:02:00    NaN
     2018-01-11 00:03:00    b
     2018-01-11 00:04:00    NaN
     2018-01-11 00:05:00    c
```

And obtaining the desired result with:

```
df.resample('1min').max().fillna(method='ffill')

Out:
                    state
     2018-01-11 00:01:00    a
     2018-01-11 00:02:00    a
     2018-01-11 00:03:00    b
     2018-01-11 00:04:00    b
     2018-01-11 00:05:00    c
```

Thanks a lot!

Quentin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward fill is not really overwriting the existing value in this case.

Pandas assume that any `NaN` value should be equivalent to the previous value. In principle, `00:03:00` was indeed `NaN` (we have no entry for it), so it gets correctly filled with it's previous value `a`.

I believe the confusion is how the final minutely "aggregation" or the downsampling occurs (ie: how are the multiple values occurring during minute 3 combined). In this case, the value of the exact minute (00 seconds) is taken

The following might explain the process:

I have added an entry to your dataframe:

```
states = list('abcd')
transition_times = [
  pd.to_datetime('00:01:00'),
  pd.to_datetime('00:03:10'),
  pd.to_datetime('00:03:30'),
  pd.to_datetime('00:05:00'),
]

df = pd.DataFrame({'state': states}, index=transition_times);df
```

And here is a manual illustration:

```
df.resample("10s").asfreq()
#                     state
# 2018-01-11 00:01:00     a
# 2018-01-11 00:01:10   NaN
# 2018-01-11 00:01:20   NaN
# 2018-01-11 00:01:30   NaN
# 2018-01-11 00:01:40   NaN
# 2018-01-11 00:01:50   NaN
# 2018-01-11 00:02:00   NaN
# 2018-01-11 00:02:10   NaN
# 2018-01-11 00:02:20   NaN
# 2018-01-11 00:02:30   NaN
# 2018-01-11 00:02:40   NaN
# 2018-01-11 00:02:50   NaN
# 2018-01-11 00:03:00   NaN
# 2018-01-11 00:03:10     b
# 2018-01-11 00:03:20   NaN
# 2018-01-11 00:03:30     c
# 2018-01-11 00:03:40   NaN
# 2018-01-11 00:03:50   NaN
# 2018-01-11 00:04:00   NaN
# 2018-01-11 00:04:10   NaN
# 2018-01-11 00:04:20   NaN
# 2018-01-11 00:04:30   NaN
# 2018-01-11 00:04:40   NaN
# 2018-01-11 00:04:50   NaN
# 2018-01-11 00:05:00     d

# Forward fill 
df_ffill = df.resample("10s").asfreq().ffill()
#                     state
# 2018-01-11 00:01:00     a
# 2018-01-11 00:01:10     a
# 2018-01-11 00:01:20     a
# 2018-01-11 00:01:30     a
# 2018-01-11 00:01:40     a
# 2018-01-11 00:01:50     a
# 2018-01-11 00:02:00     a
# 2018-01-11 00:02:10     a
# 2018-01-11 00:02:20     a
# 2018-01-11 00:02:30     a
# 2018-01-11 00:02:40     a
# 2018-01-11 00:02:50     a
# 2018-01-11 00:03:00     a
# 2018-01-11 00:03:10     b
# 2018-01-11 00:03:20     b
# 2018-01-11 00:03:30     c
# 2018-01-11 00:03:40     c
# 2018-01-11 00:03:50     c
# 2018-01-11 00:04:00     c
# 2018-01-11 00:04:10     c
# 2018-01-11 00:04:20     c
# 2018-01-11 00:04:30     c
# 2018-01-11 00:04:40     c
# 2018-01-11 00:04:50     c
# 2018-01-11 00:05:00     d

# Manual Downsample
df_ffill[df_ffill.index.second == 0]
#                     state
# 2018-01-11 00:01:00     a
# 2018-01-11 00:02:00     a
# 2018-01-11 00:03:00     a
# 2018-01-11 00:04:00     c
# 2018-01-11 00:05:00     d

# ----------------------------------------

df.resample("1min").ffill()
#                     state
# 2018-01-11 00:01:00     a
# 2018-01-11 00:02:00     a
# 2018-01-11 00:03:00     a
# 2018-01-11 00:04:00     c
# 2018-01-11 00:05:00     d
```

Comment: Thanks for a very clear and helpful answer. I adapted it to my use case by rounding the datetime index at desired precision before doing the resampling. For more detail about the context (tracking software versions among a user base from upgrade date records), here is a little [notebook](https://github.com/qagren/datamusings/blob/master/version-count-timeline.ipynb) for those interested.

Answer (score 3):

`.ffill` (ie forward fill) will use the last observation to fill forwards from the first item until it is replaced by a new observation. Moving forwards through your timestamps, at the `00:03:00` timestamp the "b" observation hasn't happened yet so it uses the last valid observation ("a").

The opposite of this method is `.bfill` (backfill) which works in the reverse order to fill backwards, eg:

```
In: df.resample('1min').bfill()
Out:
                     state
    2018-01-11 00:01:00     a
    2018-01-11 00:02:00     b
    2018-01-11 00:03:00     b
    2018-01-11 00:04:00     c
    2018-01-11 00:05:00     c
```

More details in the docs: [pandas.DataFrame.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna)